# how to get the version of a loaded kernel module in docker container

Tags: docker, kernel-modules

`lsmod` can list the loaded modules inside the container.

```
Module                  Size  Used by
pci_hyperv_intf        16384  1 mlx5_core
igb_uio                20480  2
uio                    20480  5 igb_uio
```

but if I want to check the version of the igb_uio module with `modinfo` I got this:
`modinfo: ERROR: Module alias igb_uio not found`

there is a folder with /sys/module/igb_uio and the content is:

```
ls /sys/module/igb_uio/
coresize  drivers  holders  initsize  initstate  notes  parameters  refcnt  sections  srcversion  supported  taint  uevent
```

but no *.ko file - so how can I get the version info of this loaded module?

Answer (score 0):

> lsmod can list the loaded modules inside the container.

A container does not have it own kernel nor kernel modules but uses the host's kernel and modules.
lsmod gives you the loaded modules for the host operation system.

Comment: thanks - how can be checked the versions of the loaded modules?